# Calculator won't perform basic arithmetic calculations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am relatively new to VBA and have been trying to learn it. I started by trying to code a calculator and programming it to perform basic calculations such as add, divide, subtract, and multiply. However, when I try to execute those function, using the code seen below, the calculator does not compile and perform the said calculations.

```
Private Sub cmdBtnEql_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrOcccered
     
     If txtDisplay = "Cannot divide by Zero" Then txtDisplay = Empty
     
     
     If txtRes <> "" And calVal Then
        FNum = Val(txtDisplay): SNum = Val(txtRes)
        Select Case calVal
            Case "Add"
                txtRes = FNum + SNum
            Case "Minus"
                txtRes = FNum - SNum
            Case "Multiplication"
                txtRes = FNum * SNum
            Case "Divide"
                If SNum = 0 Then
                    txtRes = "Cannot divide by zero"
                Else
                    txtRes = FNum / SNum
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
ErrOcccered:

End Sub
```

However, this procedure does not actually perform the aforementioned calculations. I am able to click on the buttons and the corresponding numbers do display in the text-box on the user-form, with no calculations done. This code is not mine personally, I am using another code I found online and trying to understand how all the syntax and semantics work within VBA. I appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The key bit of logic seems to be `Select Case calVal` but you have given us no idea what `calVal` is or how it obtains its value. We could maybe guess -- but it would be better if you *tell* us. As far as how you paste code -- highlight it and hit `Ctrl + k` (or use the code icon in the edit window).

Comment: What are you *doing* with the value `txtRes`? You seem to be doing nothing at all with it and then are wondering why nothing at all is happening. This sub doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a break point on this line of your code.
`If txtRes <> "" And calVal Then`
The step through your code with F8 and find out what it does exactly.

You will find that it never gets past this line because there is a test whether `calVal` has a value other than zero. Of course, calVal is supposed to hold a word, like "Add", and therefore can never have a numeric value other than zero.

Change this test to

```
If txtRes <> "" And len(calVal) > 0 Then
```

but still use the method with F8 to check on your code.

BTW, `txtRes = FNum + SNum` is technically correct but actually confusing. One of the commentators above mistook txtRes to be a variable. The better syntax is to include the default property in the code.

```
txtRes.Value = FNum + SNum
```